# Is Jelastic (or any PaaS) robust and reliable enough for enterprise Saas?

Tags: enterprise, paas, jelastic

Would you trust Jelastic if you were to use it for a SaaS application targeted at Enterprise customers?

I'm using it right now for its ease of use in creating a stack for a Java applcation. But it almost feels *too* easy.

What are you thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Jelastic is a universal product, designed and developed to satisfy the requirements of both expert and average users.
Ease and versatility are significant advantages of Jelastic. End user doesn't have to be a professional to use our product. But at the same time, Jelastic provides great opportunities for those people who use it.

If I needed a platform for SaaS application targeted at Enterprise,  I would definitely choose Jelastic.

Comment: Do you work for jelastic?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot directly answer your question (since Layershift are a Jelastic hosting provider), but I can give you more background information that may help with your decision:

Jelastic is provided via a number of different hosting providers right around the world. That means you can combine the ease of use functionality that you mentioned, and use it together with the hosting provider that suits your needs best in terms of physical location, infrastructure details, support, SLAs etc.

Jelastic is also available in a "private cloud" model which allows you to use it either as a self-hosted on-premise solution, or remotely hosted at any datacentre (for example, any existing Jelastic hosting provider can offer this to you easily).

So there's a wide choice of possible solutions available to help you find the best option for your particular needs.

In contrast, IaaS options offered by AWS, Azure, Google etc. give you a single provider. You might like their platform but not their SLA options/prices etc., or you might like their SLA but not their platform - there is no diversity in their offerings.

Comment: Damiean, I think you have helped me once before, appreciate it. I agree with you that Jelastic has great pricing but the SLA and support quality is in question, very often i have to wait for a very long time get support even it is impacting my production service.

Comment: The SLA and support quality depends on the hosting provider. I cannot speak for others, but our support quality is very well respected + our inclusive SLA is more robust than ones offered as very expensive paid extras on other IaaS and PaaS solutions.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is NO.

For enterprise product not only we need to consider product itself we also need to take support quality into consideration.

I have been using Jelastic for almost two years and the biggest issues is support quality, the thing is Jelastic Hosting Partners are not trained with Jelastic knowledge, and the support team from Jelastic Hosting Partners can only act as middle man for Jelastic so the real support comes from Jelastic itself, the turnover time is too long for enterprise.

As time of writing, I already waited for my issue for 6 days, and still no response, come on, this is affecting my production!

Comment: Please, give us more details about problems you have and we will investigate the situation and find the best way to resolve it. Jelastic is concerned about the quality of service and your feedback is very appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am using Jelastic platform provided by Tsukaeru in Japan, the problem is intermittently some of cloudlets I created won't have external network access, I reproduced this issue and kept the cloudlet for support to troubelshooting, however, I logged my case on March 18 so far I only received some robot like response: "we are working on your issue.. blabla.." which is not helpful at all. This is not my first time to have this kind of terrible support experience and I seriously Jelastic is mature enough for enterprise.

Comment: It's NOT true to say that the real support comes from Jelastic. Just like if you buy a server with some Microsoft software, the support is usually / predominantly provided by the hosting company (not Microsoft) - and the quality and timeliness of the support will vary accordingly.

Comment: Basically just because 1 hosting provider offers bad support, it does not mean that Jelastic as a solution cannot meet your needs. You can review https://jelastic.cloud to see the full list of available providers and some lightweight comparison between them.

Comment: Features are part of product just like support, great features with bad support don't make great product. I love Jelastic features and it meets all my needs, my only concern is I can't get enough support when there are some production issues. btw, I am also using another Jelastic hosting partner in Asia, I have similar support experience...

Comment: https://jelastic.cloud currently lists 1 provider with 5-star support rating (PacHosting in Hong Kong) - https://jelastic.cloud/?support=5&regions=AS Maybe give them a try? If you've already used them and have bad experiences, give your feedback to Jelastic https://jelastic.com/contact/ so they can find better hosting partners in Asia.

Comment: Thanks Damien, I am also with PackHosting and their support stuff has great attitude but again their response is slow as they are waiting for Jelastic to provide them backend support, overall, i am happy with PacHosting. Anyway, we have already designed our system to be high availability so I will handle these issue ourselves. Thanks agian for your help Damien!